# How does Visual Studio 2019 discover TypeScript definition files?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2019, intellisense

I have a project that was built before DefinitelyTyped stuff was moved from nuget to npm, and before TypeScript itself was typically installed as a package through npm or nuget. I have installed the latest TypeScript SDK, but I want to remove all the "old" type definitions and install them again from npm. I want to know how VS finds those files when it's calculating errors and intellisense.

Previously they were installed (by nuget) into `scripts\typings`. Of course if install by npm this is no longer the case. Does VS simple "notice" there's a `node_modules` folder and go looking in there for them? What if the `node_modules` folder is in the root of the solution, and not the root of the project?